# Can I make a ContentDialog.Async() await another ContentDialog.Async() in UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, events, uwp

I'm running an UWP app with 2 pages. In MainPage I start a ContentDialog Async method which opens page2 in a frame. In page2 I have a secondary ContentDialog which I open by pressing a button. 
In the Button_Click method I want to close the running Async() method and await to start the next one until I am 100% sure the first one is closed.

The problem I encounter now is that the program crashes if I press the secondary ContentDialog's buttons too fast after it opens.

I've tried thread sleeping but that only delays the problem.

Mainpage(CustomerInfoPage):

```
transactionContent = new ContentDialog();
Frame transactionFrame = new Frame();
transactionFrame.Navigate(typeof(TransactionPage), selectedAccount);

transactionContent.Content = transactionFrame;

transactionContent.ShowAsync();
```

Page2(TransactionPage):

```
private async void DepositButton_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CustomerInfoPage.transactionContent.Hide();
    ContentDialog confirmationDialog = new ContentDialog
    {
        Title = "Deposit Funds.",
        Content = $"You will deposit {depositTextBox.Text} SEK.\nYour new balance will be: {ReceivedAccount.Balance + deposit} SEK",
        PrimaryButtonText = "CONFIRM",
        SecondaryButtonText = "CANCEL"

    };
    confirmationDialog.PrimaryButtonClick += ConfirmationDialog_PrimaryButtonClick;
    await confirmationDialog.ShowAsync();

    async void ConfirmationDialog_PrimaryButtonClick(ContentDialog _sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
    {
        confirmationDialog.Hide();
    }
    CustomerInfoPage.transactionContent.ShowAsync();
}
```

So this works as long as you don't call the ConfirmationDialog_PrimaryButtonClick too fast by clicking on it instantly after it is opened.

Answer (score 1):

This is introduced in the [UWP documentation about Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/dialogs-and-flyouts/dialogs#contentdialog-in-appwindow-or-xaml-islands).

> There can only be one ContentDialog open per thread at a time. Attempting to open two ContentDialogs will throw an exception, even if they are attempting to open in separate AppWindows.

So you can't start the second `CotnentDialog` while the first `ContentDialog` is still running.

Best regards.

Comment: I know this, this is why i use the `.Hide();` right before i open the next one. But if im fast with my clicking and click something in the new contentdialog faster than a second after it opens, the `.Hide()` method never completes before the next `Async()` runs, causing the program to "think" i am running 2 content dialogs.

If i wait for 1 second before pressing anything the program works as expected.

Comment: Hi, when you call the `ContentDialog.Hide()`, `ContentDialog` is in the state of **Closing**. In fact, `ContentDialog` will not be in **Closed** until `await ContentDialog.ShowAsync()` is executed. So calling the `Hide` method doesn't mean that your `ContentDialog` has finished working on the current thread.

Comment: Ah I see! Solved it by separating the ShowAsync() methods into two methods wich i called with await from the buttonclick method! Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Maybe we can use the flyout

Answer (score 1):

As @Richard Zhang - MSFT said in previous answer

> So you can't start the second CotnentDialog while the first
>   ContentDialog is still running.

If you wish to close the `ContentDialog` from previous page right before opening new `ContentDialog` you can use the code from below which will close any `ContentDialog` which is currently open.

```
var openedpopups = VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups(Window.Current);
foreach (var popup in openedpopups)
{
   if(popup.Child is ContentDialog)
   {
      (popup.Child as ContentDialog).hide();
   }
}
```

Comment: I do close the ContentDialog with `confirmationDialog.Hide();` in my `ConfirmationDialog_PrimaryButtonClick`(Page2). 

And then i run the public static `CustomerInfoPage.transactionContent.ShowAsync();` (Page1)

Comment: In this case use the above code to check if the any content dialog is still open. if its open then wait for it in a while loop and then call `ShowAsync()`